# NestJS Nats message ack

Tags: nestjs, nats.io

Is there a way to manually acknowledge a message if I use NATS for async communication in a NestJS app? This is very common use case where the message is acknowledge after a service is done processing it. If the message is not acknowledged, the server would need to redeliver (just like in the old NATS Streaming library).

```
@EventPattern({ cmd: 'user:create' })
async createUser(@Payload() user: UserDto, @Ctx() context: NatsContext) {
  await this.emailsService.sendWelcomeEmail(user)
  // need to manually acknowledge the message here but the docs do not provide a way to do so.
}
```

Comment: Your nest tag is wrong. If you fix it you may get help.

Answer (score 0):

when using nats-streaming
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs-plugins/nestjs-nats-streaming-transport

```
@EventPattern(Patterns.UserCreated)
  public async stationCreatedHandler(@Payload() data: { id: number, name: string }, @Ctx() context: NatsStreamingContext) {
    console.log(`received message: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
    context.message.ack()
  }

//setup 
    {
        durableName: 'user-queue-group',
        manualAckMode: true,
        deliverAllAvailable: true,
      } /* TransportSubscriptionOptions */ ,
    ),
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that good old STAN has message acks. However, I'm really trying to use the new NATS (I believe it's JET Stream). However, without message acks it might not fit my use case.